# Keep getting black diamond question mark despite everything in UTF-8 in a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

In a PHP script that should perform some tasks (no output except for logging messages) I extract data from MySQL DB. I noticed that echoing some data has black diamond question mark like `Componenti Elettronici�`. Seems that everything is in UTF-8 and I don't know where that diamond comes from (no trace in DB field, apparently) and, most important, how to remove/replace

On top of PHP script I have:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

DB table collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci`. Database connection is also `utf8mb4`

What I tried so far:

- `echo strlen($str);` outputs `23`, that is the real 22 chars of `Componenti Elettronici` + black diamond
- `echo mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_list_encodings(), true);` outputs `UTF-8`
- `echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_list_encodings(), true), "UTF-8", $str);` does not change output: the black diamond is still there, of course because I'm converting from UTF-8 to UTF-8, thus doing absolutely nothing

That black diamond prevents me from indexing data in an Elasticsearch environment, that's the big problem

So, why I have that black diamond? How can I remove or replace it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you also set the charset whenever you connect to your database?

Comment: @D1__1: yes, I set it to utf8mb4

Comment: Have you tried using `utf8mb4` as the table collation?

Comment: oh, sorry, I just realized that table is yet utf8mb4, not utf8: I update question

Comment: I noticed in Chrome Dev Tools that the black diamond question mark was due to `NUL` byte: just used `trim()` function and it is gone now

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored